# Twisted win32 SerialPort sometimes blocks

Tags: python, serial-port, twisted

I am using Twisted (v15.3.0) with a `SerialPort` on a windows machine to communicate with a device that is always connected. Occasionally I have noticed the `SerialPort` going quiet ie. it stops receiving/responding to any communication. I have a `loopingCall` that calls a `sendLine` function every 10 seconds and I see this function continuously being called because it prints to the screen before running `sendLine`. However, the command port goes quiet and I no longer receive expected responses from the port.

The physical serial port seems to be working fine because restarting my program fixes this issue. I am wondering if I should close and open the serial port at every expected write/read block. However, the time until the quite time occur has been between 2560 and 10350 seconds (because I log the output), which is too long to simulate or reproduce in a meaningful way.

I would like to know if there are work arounds to using SerialPorts in a discontinous fashion. For example, a `loopingCall` to somehow **timeout**.

---

Related bug report is http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/1248, but the proposed 'fix' (read: hack) at the end of the tracker no longer works.

Comment: It sounds like you should be continuing the discussion on ticket 1248, and perhaps coming forward with a patch; this is just a bug report, not really an SO question.

Comment: Ok, Glyph, I will reword my question to get at what I really want: an alternative that does not rely on continuously open serialport

Comment: It seems there's no way to close a serial port that Twisted opens using public API.  In 10 years of supporting serial ports on Windows this is the first such request I've heard.  That said, there's no reason why this functionality shouldn't be available, so you could submit that as well as a fix to 1248.